# Is memory freed after using StringValueCStr?

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I use StringValueCStr to convert ruby String to char*. Do i need to free memory when this new C string is no longer needed?

If this new C string is freed automatically, does this mean i should copy it if i plan on saving it in my C structures for later use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StringValueCStr` returns the same pointer that `StringValuePtr` does -- which is the internal string buffer of the object.

That buffer could change or be invalidated by any subsequent mutation of the String instance (or, of course, a garbage collection), so yes you should copy it if you need to keep it around.